# Convert Array data to html table

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

im having some issues with a array data that i got form a json file, but i guess the issue maybe is with the json structure that that i converted in array using json decode and file_get_contents.

Basicall this is the array strucutre:

```
#items: array:4 [▼
    "Monday, 1 de Fev de 2021" => array:5 [▼
      "PM" => array:7 [▼
        1 => "1140-10"
        2 => "8498-25"
        3 => "7076-19"
        4 => "3380-20"
        5 => "8194-24"
        6 => "8288-22"
        7 => "687-22"
      ]
      "PT" => array:7 [▼
        1 => "6406-2"
        2 => "2976-19"
        3 => "6029-8"
        4 => "8130-8"
        5 => "7530-8"
        6 => "1071-18"
        7 => "064-16"
      ]
      "PTV" => array:7 [▶]
      "PTN" => array:7 [▶]
    ]
    "Sat, 31 de Jan de 2021" => array:2 [▼
      "PTM" => array:7 [▶]
      "PT" => array:7 [▶]
    ]
```

Basically the date is the table caption, and the index with the letters eg: "PTV","PM","PT"...", are the theader th titles.

And inside of the "PM" for example there are some results:

```
 1 => "1140-10"
 2 => "8498-25"
 3 => "7076-19"
 4 => "3380-20"
 5 => "8194-24"
 6 => "8288-22"
 7 => "687-22"
```

Where the indexes (1,2,3..) Are the prize, and the values after each index are the results.

I need to construct my table to be like this image above

[image]

This is my code:

```xml
@if(sizeof($results) > 0)
  @foreach($results as $date => $result)
    <div class="col-xl-12">
      <table class="table">
        <caption>
          {{ $date }}
        </caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="hoje" class="tabla-header"></th>
            @foreach($result as $banca => $re)
              <th id="{{ $banca }}" class="tabla-header">{{ $banca }}</th>
            @endforeach
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {{ sizeof($result) }}
          @for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              @for ($n = 0; $n < sizeof($result); $n++)
                <td>{{ $result[] }}/td>
              @endfor
            </tr>
          @endfor
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: `@for ($n = 0; $n < sizeof($result); $n++)` If you change this loop to a foreach you can access the values by `<td>{{ $result[$key][$i] }}</td>` and I believe it would work?

Comment: not really, the issue im having is each index (PTM) have the data populate in each one, and i need to call the first position of PTM and than the others, the way is structure is not quite simple to construct the way i want the table.

Comment: Well i belive i did it.

Answer (score 0):

create a database and insert into table information . next with console make:controller // make a controller

make a method ...( select information of database)

```
          $var1 = DB::table("table_name")->get('column_1');// first use DB namespace
          $var2 = DB::table("table_name")->get('column_2');
          $var2 = $var2[
          // and other get columns table
          return view('view_name',['tr1' => $var1,'tr2' => $var2 /* and etc */);
}
```

and view is under code

```
<!DOCTYPE htl>
<html>
<table class="table"> <!-- table class ; you create a table class in your code -->
<tr>
<th>{{$var1[0][0]->column_name}}</th>
<th>{{$var1[0][1]->column_name}}</th>
<th>{{$...}}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> {{$avr2[0][0]->column_name}} </th>
<th> {{$var2[0][1]->coumn_name}} </th>
<!-- and continue above code -->
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

first you select info of db and show them in view